# schema validation fails although parameter is available

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, joi

I created a REST api and want to validate the body and the params before calling the controller logic. For the validation I use **Joi** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi).

Let's say I have a route with one url parameter and some body variables. The `params` object contains this url parameter but Joi still returns a `400`. The detail message is

> "userId" is required

I tried to create a minimalistic example showing my code. To reproduce the error create the **app.js** file

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use('/users', require('./routes/users.js'));

app.listen(3000);
```

Due to the fact each validation fails there is only one route required to test it. Create **users.js** with the following content

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const usersController = require('../controllers/users.js');
const usersControllerPolicy = require('../policies/users.js');

router.get('/:userId', usersControllerPolicy.getUserById, usersController.getUserById);

module.exports = router;
```

And this **users.js** controller file

```
exports.getUserById = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { userId } = req.params;
    return res.status(200).json("everything is fine");
};
```

When it comes to the policy I created the **users.js** policy which adds the required schema to the middleware

```
const joi = require('joi');

const schemaValidation = require('../middleware/schemaValidation.js');

module.exports = {
    getUserById: (req, res, next) => {
        schemaValidation({
            params: {
                userId: joi.string().guid().required()
            },
            body: {}
        }, req, res, next);
    }
}
```

and then the schema gets validated by my **schemaValidation.js**

```
const joi = require('joi');

module.exports = (schema, req, res, next) => {
    const { error } = joi.validate(req, schema);

    if (error)
        return res.status(400).json("something went wrong");

    next(); // execute the controller logic
}
```

As you can see I pass in the whole `req` object. I do this because sometimes I have to validate the body and the params. The url parameter `userId` is not found by Joi so I get returned a status code of 400.

How can I fix my middleware validation to validate both objects within the `req` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually Joi has access to the `userId` and can properly validate it or not, here's why:

```
// replace this
const { error } = joi.validate(req, schema);
// by this
console.log(req.params.userId);
const { error } = joi.validate(req, schema);
console.log(error.toString());
```

console output while visiting `localhost:3000/users/10`:

```
10
ValidationError: child "params" fails because [child "userId" fails because ["userId" must be a valid GUID]]
```

and while visiting an URL including a valid GUID in the params, like ``:

```
ad3756ae-2661-4d8c-aeda-dd51deef5ea9
ValidationError: "_readableState" is not allowed. "readable" is not allowed. "_events" is not allowed. "_eventsCount" is not allowed. "_maxListeners" is not allowed. "socket" is not allowed. "connection" is not allowed. "httpVersionMajor" is not allowed. "httpVersionMinor" is not allowed. "httpVersion" is not allowed. "complete" is not allowed. "headers" is not allowed. "rawHeaders" is not allowed. "trailers" is not allowed. "rawTrailers" is not allowed. "aborted" is not allowed. "upgrade" is not allowed. "url" is not allowed. "method" is not allowed. "statusCode" is not allowed. "statusMessage" is not allowed. "client" is not allowed. "_consuming" is not allowed. "_dumped" is not allowed. "next" is not allowed. "baseUrl" is not allowed. "originalUrl" is not allowed. "_parsedUrl" is not allowed. "query" is not allowed. "res" is not allowed. "route" is not allowed
```

So Joi has access to everything that it needs and works as expected.

---

So why the error 400?

Well, as logged in the console, Joi fails the validation for `req`. That is because, by default, Joi doesn't accept unknown params in an object. You can change this with `.unknown(true)` which validates an object even if unknown parameters are included.

So, in your case, you should replace the code of `policies/users.js` by the following:

```
const joi = require('joi');

const schemaValidation = require('../middleware/schemaValidation.js');

module.exports = {
    getUserById: (req, res, next) => {

        // properly defines a schema with optional parameters
        const schema = joi.object({
            params: joi.object({
                userId: joi.string().guid().required()
            }).unknown(true),
        }).unknown(true);

        schemaValidation(schema, req, res, next);
    }
}
```

Now, when you visit again an URL including a valid GUID (like http://localhost:3000/users/ad3756ae-2661-4d8c-aeda-dd51deef5ea9), everything happens as expected and `""everything is fine"` is being sent by the server!

Comment: yes this worked :) so I should always go for this approach? https://pastebin.com/s5eVTfFJ

Comment: Yes, I would indeed recommend that! I'd also recommend you to take a look at [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/) and [AJV](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) - used together, they also allow for API validation. The big plus is that the validation logic can be stored in JSON instead of JS-only, which allows for increase compatibility.

Comment: I'm glad that it worked! But remember this weird [Stack Overflow rule](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) - don't say thank you in a comment, instead upvote, accept, or award the bounty ;)

Comment: yes, well I have to wait six more hours to award the bounty :)